# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I watched this yt-video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi4i7Q0zrBs
to learn something about neural networks and how they work.
Now I've wrote down the exact code from the Video but unfortunately it didnt work out correctly for me.

I would be pleased if someone could help me with my question

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

# load dataset of handwritten digits
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# normalise training data and cut down between 0 and 255 (greyscale)
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

# y_values already declared because they are from 0-9
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# flatten layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))

# all neurons are connected with the layers, units make neurons you wanna have in layer
# 2 dense hidden layers
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))

# output layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)
print(loss)

model.save("digits.model")


for x in range(1,4):
    img = cv.imread(f"{x}.png")[:,:,0]
    # invert to make it black and white digits
    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    print(f"The result ist probably: {np.argmax(prediction)}")
    plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3nEH.png

Comment: Please post the **full** error trace here as *text*, *not* image; see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the following code due to shape mismatch:

```
for x in range(1,4):
    img = cv.imread(f"{x}.png")[:,:,0]
    # invert to make it black and white digits
    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    print(f"The result ist probably: {np.argmax(prediction)}")
    plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
```

Replacing the above code with the following code helped in solving the issue.

```
for x in range(1,4):
    img = cv.imread(f"{x}.png")
    #invert to make it black and white digits
    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
    img=tf.image.resize(tf.squeeze(img),(28,28))
    img=tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img)
    img=np.rollaxis(img,-1,0)
    print(img.shape)
    prediction = model.predict((img))
    print(f"The result ist probably: {np.argmax(prediction)}")
    plt.imshow(tf.squeeze(img), cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
```

Please find the complete code in this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/18a922e7e34febaea7eaf6a09da614ec/untitled123.ipynb). Thank you!